# Can you have two Segues from different View Controllers going to one View Controller Swift 3

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am currently trying to send myslideMenuVC to my ProfileVC upon tapping a cell. I go to instantiate the ProfileVC with a storyboard identifier , but I already have a segue to this view controller from my LoginVC. Are you aloud to have 2 segues on one view controller? If yes, why wont this this segue work, because I am recieving this error: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException, Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'profileFromSlideMenu''

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //self.selectedPost(index: 0)
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            if let myProfileVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileFromSlideMenu") as? Profile {
            self.present(myProfileVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            handleLogout(Any.self)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to do that. The problem is you have either not set up an identifier for that particular view controller or you have a typo in the identifier in your code.

Comment: The view controller had a different id, I completely forgot to change that! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are allowed to have several segues going from different View controllers to a single View controller.

The problem is you have either not set up an identifier for that particular view controller or you have a typo in the identifier in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the View Controller, make sure the StoryboardID is the same as the one in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Is "profileFromSlideMenu" the Storyboard ID of your vc or a segue identifier?
storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ... requires a storyboard id. 
[You can set it like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Qbg.png)

Yes, you can have multiple segues to a vc.

When you made sure your storyboard identifier is correct, try so use:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "YOUR STORYBOARD NAME (MAIN?)", bundle: nil)
```

instead of self.storyboard.
Hope this helps.